# Highlighting search text with Danish letters in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview displaying items from a database.
I highlights the string from textbox matching the text in the gridview like this.

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = Regex.Replace(e.Row.Cells[0].Text, txtSøg.Text.Trim(), delegate (Match match)
        {
            return string.Format("<span style = 'background-color:#b56612'>{0}</span>", match.Value);
        }, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
```

It works, but not with Danish letters (æøåÆØÅ). Then it dosent highlight anything.
How do i make that work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming "Søg" means "Search" and contains user input, are you sure you want to put unescaped text into a RegEx? Anyway read [ask] and provide a [mcve] including example input and output. I [cannot reproduce your issue](https://www.ideone.com/kyFVRr).

Comment: You are right. "Søg" means searh. Sorry about that. The issue is, that if the textbox.text has Danish letters in it, theres no match. I have a RegEx for the textbox it self.

Comment: Read my comment again. Click the last link. The code you show does not reproduce the issue you claim. Create a [mcve] including example input and output.

Comment: Just for info to others with the same problem. The soloution was to set "BoundField HtmlEncode="false" in the Gridview. I suppose i was way off. Thanks anyway.